# Postgres Query Statment - Date Issue

Tags: pgadmin

I have a Postgres database and I am trying to show a Col on the sheet the number of hours between the start and finish of their shift.

Currently the query is super simple - See below

```
select *, datediff(hours start, finish) from public.volass
```

Table Details

```html
CREATE TABLE volass
(
  id bigint, -- 
  start timestamp without time zone,
  finish timestamp without time zone,
  shiftype bigint,
  notes bigint,
  hidden boolean,
  linkedass bigint,
  rolename text
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE volass
  OWNER TO tbourne;
COMMENT ON COLUMN volass.id IS '
';
```

I know that this is a super dumb question but trying to get it to work is doing my head in.

Comment: You've made zero effort to write the query yourself (SELECT * FROM table is not an effort to try and calculate anything). See the DATEDIFF() function in the Postgres documentation.

Comment: I think I may have placed the wrong code in. I had attemtped it. I am just getting confused with how I get where I put the datediff bit into it.

Comment: What is you question? You claim your query works. What is the problem?